# Return unique records using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

Sorry,  for title... I haven't any idea how call it.

In my database I have records with dates:

```
2012-02-03
2012-02-03
2012-02-05
2012-02-05
2012-02-05
2012-02-06
```

And how make a linq query to display just records with the single dates, I mean:

```
2012-02-03
2012-02-05
2012-02-06
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Distinct()`, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<string> distinctDates = dates.Distinct()
```

For more complicated cases, you may also use GroupBy(), but Distinct is enough for this